# Replace Similar Worded Line through SED

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file sample_init.ora

There are 2 lines in the file.

```
db_create_file_dest="DATAG"
control_files=('DATAG/DBNAME/controlfile/control01.ctl','DATAG/DBNAME/controlfile/control02.ctl')
```

Now, I would like to change only the 2nd line from DATAG to DATAC2. Is there a way? I tried many SED/AWK forums but left with no options. A SED based reply would be HIGHLY regarded.

Comment: In the second line there are 2 instances of `DATAG`. Are you wanting both changed? Or just one?

Comment: Those other two end with `/` and begin with `'` unlike the first one, so that should be fairly easy to use.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along : I want only the 'DATAG/ to be changed, Hence the post. (The one in the 2nd line)

Comment: There are *two* 'DATAG/'s in the second line. Would you like *both* of those changed?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along : Yes. I do.

Comment: Okay, posted the solution.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along I've voted it up too. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want `sed '/^control_files/ s/DATAG/DATAC2/g' file`

Comment: @steeldriver This is working just fine. Worth an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question refers to "similar" lines - but doesn't tell us how we should distinguish them.

For example, to replace all instances of `DATAG` by `DATAC2` **only** in lines that start with the string `control_files` you could use

```
sed '/^control_files/ s/DATAG/DATAC2/g'
```

It should work as a general method if you replace `^control_files` with some other distinguishing pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious sed solution would be:

```
sed 2s/DATAG/DATAC2/g sample_init.ora > new_file.ora
```

or to edit in-place, if your sed supports `-i`:

```
sed -i 2s/DATAG/DATAC2/g sample_init.ora
```

The sed instruction is:

- `2` - on line 2
- `s//` - search and replace
- `g` - replace every match, not just the first one

Comment: No siree! I want to change only the second line.

Comment: This does change only the second line...

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along Im sorry. Maybe i wasn't clear. These two lines come in a 360 lines document each rollout. The lines may not be in the specific order as Jeff suggested here. Is there a way ?

Comment: @AravindhanK your question clearly says "I would like to change only the 2nd line"

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. Thats why i apologized for being unclear. Sorry about that. Your answers were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that this is the *exact* format that the lines will display in the file, use:

```
sed -i 's/DATAG\//DATAC2\//g' <filename> > <new_filename>
```

This will work as the instances of DATAG in the second line have a '/' following them, whereas, in the first line, it doesn't. So, after execution, the example you gave will read:

```
db_create_file_dest="DATAG"
control_files=('DATAC2/DBNAME/controlfile/control01.ctl','DATAC2/DBNAME/controlfile/control02.ctl')
```

and it won't matter where in the file this lies.

Comment: You reigned supreme. Exactly what i needed

Comment: No bother man, remember to accept the answer so people will know the question's been answered at a glance.

Comment: @I_GNI_it_all_along : Yes. I do that immediately whenever people solves my trouble here. Thanks again

Comment: @AravindhanK  You haven't accepted any of these answers (yet).  See "to accept an answer" on https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along Right! Im a noob here. I thought voting up will help me do that. Read the wiki you gave me. Im marking it as "SOLVED" now.